# Mouse Coords to Game Coords WebGL

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, webgl

I'm trying to translate the mouse x, y coordinates into 3d world coordinates of webgl canvas.  I've gotten it working partially, but am having some trouble when the world gets rotated on any axis.

I'm using the unproject method that gets the starting/ending points of the ray and then doing a line to plane collision test for a flat plane with the normal 0, 1, 0 and the point being used is 0, 0, 0.

You can find the code at [wingsofexodus.com](http://wingsofexodus.com) by doing a view source.  The functions being used are RtoW (real to world, for mouse to world conversion), lpi (line plane intersection testing), and unproject.

It's been ages since I had to do any matrix/vector math and dusting off the books after so long is proving difficult.

The site may come up slow, my internet connection for it isn't all that great.  If it proves to be to trouble some I'll copy the code to here.

Any help or links that might help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but I see two mistakes and one needless complication:

- Complication: Instead of duplicating the code to compute the view matrix from rotation angles etc, save a copy of it when you compute it (at the beginning of drawScene) and use that instead of `mm`. Or, make sure the matrix stack is in the right place and have `unproject` just use `mvMatrix`. This will avoid errors from that.
- You refer to the translation in what you do with the unprojection result (in `RtoW`). This is a mistake, because the translation is already included in `mm`; you're either doubling or cancelling it. After you have unprojected the mouse coordinates, you have *world coordinates* which do not need to be further modified before doing your ray collision test.
- In unproject, you are inverting the view matrix before multiplying it with the projection matrix. You can either do (pseudocode) `invert(view)*invert(projection)`, or (cheaper) `invert(projection*view)`, but you're currently doing `invert(projection*invert(view))`, which is wrong.

These are what jumped out at me, but I haven't reviewed all of your code. The unprojection looks OK when I compare it to [my own version of the same](https://github.com/kpreid/cubes/blob/02a136abe23487bcf20de4040c1ef9f320c4b64d/renderer.js#L500).

Comment: After implementing your suggestions (aside from using the matrix i used during rendering, i just prefer to keep it that way while working the kinks out)  it's working great, but the cube/texture get off center when I move the mouse away from the center of the canvas.  I've adjusted the initial rotating/translation to be a top down view so it can be seen easier.  I haven't had to much of a chance to play with it lately, but any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: I'm away from my computer for a while so I can't take a look, but from your description I wonder if you're not seeing "real" off-centeredness but the result of your projection - consider that if you're looking through a top-down perspective projection, projection rays other than that at the center of the screen are not perpendicular to the plane. Think about what exactly you want to be aligned with the cursor - for example, the top, bottom, or middle of your cube?

Comment: Oh, and I should say that you should ask that as a separate question.